# AS3 - Specific frame eventlistener?

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I have the following code to generate a new explosion movie clip. Unfortunately, the GameEvent.EXPLOSION_FINISHED event is never triggered. Is there a special event listener for each frame?

```
var exp:Explosion = new Explosion();
exp.addFrameScript(exp.totalFrames - 1, function():void {exp.stop();dispatchEvent( new GameEvent( GameEvent.EXPLOSION_FINISHED));});
exp.addEventListener(GameEvent.EXPLOSION_FINISHED, tidyUp, false, 0, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that your not dispatching the event on the exp object, but the object your chunk of code is in.  Try this:

```
exp.addFrameScript(exp.totalFrames - 1, function():void {exp.stop();exp.dispatchEvent( new GameEvent( GameEvent.EXPLOSION_FINISHED));});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.addEventListener(GameEvent.EXPLOSION_FINISHED,tidyUp);
...
function tidyUp(e:Event):void {
    var s:Object=e.target;
    if (s is Explosion) {
        var expl:Explosion=s as Explosion;
        // process your "expl" Explosion object here
    }
}
```

Should do.